# Yarn or npm? for installing dependencies in react-native

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg, react-native-cli

what should I use to install react-native dependencies? yarn or npm, in my case npm have some problems with some of dependencies.
Sometimes i use npm to install these, but i am still confused to decide which one to use permanently.

Comment: Refer this https://stackshare.io/stackups/npm-vs-yarn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both NPM and Yarn are great tools in managing your project's dependencies. There are a lot of improvements Yarn has over npm from faster speeds and stronger security. Many say that if you are already familiar with NPM that a jump to Yarn isn’t really necessary, especially with the release of version 5. Personally I will favor Yarn over NPM mainly because of the speed. But it all boils down to a matter of preference.

[Refer](https://medium.com/@j.dumadag718/yarn-vs-npm-b2d58289fb9b)

[Refer](https://stackshare.io/stackups/npm-vs-yarn)

Comment: thanks for your answer. i will continue using yarn from now onward.

Comment: Sure :) Glad it helps

Answer (score 0):

yarn is much more faster than npm. furthermore npm is also an impressive option